# Pandas - Add two columns with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add two columns with NaNs.

The behavior I want is:

1. If both are NaNs, then this column should be NaN
2. If one of them are numeric, then the value should be numeric (the NaN is treated as 0's)

---

```
a = pd.DataFrame([1, np.NaN, 4, 5])
b = pd.DataFrame([3, np.NaN, 5, np.NaN])

a+b

0   4.0
1   NaN
2   9.0
3   NaN
```

---

Is there a way to do this built-in functions?

Comment: `a.add(b,fill_value=0)` build in func add

Comment: @Wen Works great! Want to submit an answer so I can give you a checkmark?

Comment: Posted as community wiki : -) since it is dup, just hard to find it ....

Comment: @Wen Yeah, the title wasn't exactly my question, but the content is.

Comment: @user1157751 Tried to make the title on the dupe a bit better.

Comment: Here is another one that accepts any amount of series: `pd.concat((a,b), axis=1).sum(1)`

Comment: @AntonvBR feel free to modify the answer below : -)

Comment: @AntonvBR Which version of Pandas are you using? I tried the query and #1 was 0 instead of np.NaN.

reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), [a, b, c]) == pd.concat((a,b,c), axis=1).sum(1) was not equal

Comment: @user1157751 0.21 on this laptop. I'll upgrade it.

Comment: @user1157751 Ok... it seems this doesn't work anymore for 0.22.

Comment: @AntonvBR No worries, happens sometimes with Pandas.

Comment: @user1157751 Add min_count and it works:  `pd.concat((a,b,c), axis=1).sum(1,min_count=1)`

Comment: @AntonvBR Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat()` instead of the suggested `.add()` function (add also works but is less handy for multiple cols).

```
pd.concat((a,b), axis=1).sum(1, min_count=1)
```

---

Consider this **example**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series([1, np.NaN, 4, 5])
b = pd.Series([3, np.NaN, 5, np.NaN])
c = pd.Series([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN])

print(pd.concat((a,b,c), axis=1).sum(1, min_count=1))

#0    4.0
#1    NaN
#2    9.0
#3    5.0
#dtype: float64
```